# How can I expand color of column item as mush as it's parent width

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make my first color item in column expanding based on parent width ..

this is my simple code

```
    import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_engine.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class Ff extends StatefulWidget {
      const Ff({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<Ff> createState() => _FfState();
    }
    
    class _FfState extends State<Ff> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
        

  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                  child: Text('Hello world',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),) // here i need to expanding my color 
              ),
             Container(
               width: 200,// Note : This width item is not fixed, it depends on user input text, it could be changed depends on user all the time 
               height: 100,
             )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OK now I have the parent container that has a red color, and my second item in `Column` is not fixed all the time. it depends on user width text and i make the width 200 for example only ..

Now the output in `UI` looks like the following:

[image]

but I need it to look like this:

[image]

I find way to make my green container width `infinity` work, but the problem is the whole parent red container will be expanding that I don't want like following

```
           Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.green,
                  child: Text('Hello world',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
              ),
```

[image]

Final note: in my case the width of my red container (parent one) it's width comes based on my SECOND ITEM in my column which is Text input and it could be changed all the time but I make the width 200 for example .. so I can't make direct width to the parent it's self

How can I achieve this? Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your example this should work:

```
class Ff extends StatefulWidget {
  const Ff({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Ff> createState() => _FfState();
}

class _FfState extends State<Ff> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: IntrinsicWidth(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Row(children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child: Text(
                              'Hello world',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            )
                            ))
                  ]),
                  Container(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 100,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: thannnnnnnnnnnnnnnks like billion @ivo Beckers .. Here we benefit from experience .. 3 years i am learning flutter  i have never know about IntrinsicWidth .. really thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch
```

inside your column. That force to set max width posible inside the parent